# Open a new window more than once in IE via target="_blank" in a link tag?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a page with a ton of links (foo). If a user opens a link they get a new window (bar) via target="_BLANK" in the link. But if they go back to foo and click on another link instead of another new window (bar2), bar navigates to the new link.

This is only an issue in IE Fx opens a new tab. I need IE to do the same. Or open a new window.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name the targets _blank1, _blank2, etc.

Answer (score 5):

In Internet Explorer, the case of the target property matters. You should set your target to "_blank" instead of "_BLANK". If you want to try it out, [go right ahead](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_target).